# How to automatically convert all video files in a folder at a scheduled time?

Tags: windows-7, video, conversion, automation, scheduled-tasks

More specifically, how do I convert MPG files to 3GP everyday at 3.00am?

```
C:\TV\*.mpg -> C:\TV\*.3gp
```

It would be more convenient if one video converter program could do all of this but I'm open to using different tools and command line scripting if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and write a batch script to control FFmpeg through the command line. Once the script works as expected, use Windows Scheduler to run the script everyday at 3.00am

Comment: Download Windows x86 Build [here](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/)

Comment: It's better to [download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) from official web-site. In case of windows, direct link is [this](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.7z)